# Overloading >> operator for inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

How would I make this work? The professor instructed us to use private variables. Do I have to set up new variables to input Person's private members in the Student constructor? What is the most efficient way of making this work?

Thank you in advance.

```
class Person
{
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Person&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Person&);
private:
    char* m_name;
    int m_age;
    string m_ssn;
public:
    Person() = default;
    Person(char*, int, const string&);
    Person(const Person&);
    ~Person();
    void setName(char*);
    char* getName();
    void setAge(int);
    int getAge();
    void setSSN(string);
    string getSSN();
    Person& operator=(const Person&);
};

// ...

class Student : public Person
{
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Student&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Student&);
private:
    float m_gpa;
public:
    Student() = default;
    Student(char*, int, const string&, float);
    Student(const Student&);
    void setGPA(float);
    float getGPA();
    Student& operator=(const Student&);
};

istream& operator>>(istream &is, Student &iStudent)
{
    // ?

    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Implement `operator>>` and `operator<<` using the base class.
2. Use `virtual` member functions to redirect the implementation.

```
class Person
{
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Person&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Person&);

    ....

   public:

    virtual std::istream& read(std::istream&) { ... }
    virtual std::ostream& write(std::ostream&) const { ... }

    ...
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Person& person)
{
   return persone.read(is);
}

std::stream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Person const& person)
{
   return persone.write(os);
}

class Student : public Person
{
   ...

   public:

    virtual std::istream& read(std::istream&) { ... }
    virtual std::ostream& write(std::ostream&) const { ... }

   ...
};
```